# Containing provider re-rendered by changes in a render props child using Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have something like:

```
const higherOrderComponent = (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      <CustomProvider
        render={({isLoading, playNote, playNoteAtTime, stopNote}) => {

            return <WrappedComponent />;
        }
      />
  }
};
```

I have a single redux store higher up in my app and when the user interacts with 'WrappedComponent', it dispatches an action to the store, which causes 'higherOrderComponent' to re-render.

This hasn't been a problem before, as I have been favoring stateless components, and letting the new state wash through the full app on state change worked with no performance issues.

The Custom provider is asynchronously loading some files though, so now there is a noticable issue.

An idea for a solution is to introduce state in the component at the 'higherOrderComponent' level. When the component is first loaded, I will populate the state from the store props.

Then I could save up and dispatch actions to update the store later at an opportune time.

I'm not sure if I have created an anti-pattern with the above though (I'm using a Higher Order Component with 'Render props' at the same time).

Or if anyone can recommend a better solution?

**edit**
I was asked to show what CustomProvider is doing so I have added part of it here:

```
class SampleProvider extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    instrumentNames: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    audioContext: PropTypes.instanceOf(window.AudioContext),
    render: PropTypes.func
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    currentInstrument: 'mooga'
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.playNote = this.playNote.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      activeAudioNodes: {},
      instrument: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    sampleLoader.init(this.props.audioContext, sampleFilePaths).then(loadedSamplesBuffers => {
      this.samplesBuffers = loadedSamplesBuffers;
      console.log('End: loading samples');
    });
  }

  playNote = midiNumber => {

    let play = samplePlayer(this.props.audioContext, this.props.mainOutput, this.samplesBuffers);

    play(midiNumber, 0, null, null, this.props.currentInstrument);

  };
```

Comment: Please, clarify what CustomProvider looks like and how you use higherOrderComponent, so it causes the problem you describe.

Comment: @estus I have clarified and added the CustomProvider code above

Comment: A possible design issue I see is that you maintain local state and business logic apart from Redux, so possible benefits of Redux are discarded for unknown reason. I don't see a problem with the use of render function, but WrappedComponent doesn't get props that are provided by the function. *The Custom provider is asynchronously loading some files though, so now there is a noticable issue* - I see no problem here because a component isn't remounted, so the logic in componentDidMount isn't retriggered on updates. You can skip updates with shouldComponentUpdate if needed, too.